# CSS Text Fade In/Out to Different Text

Tags: javascript, css, text, fade

Basically, on a website I want to display a number of elements in the same space one after the other with a fade effect to transition between them; this would be used to display quotes from customers on a website. I've achieved this before using images and using CSS effects to fade in/out from the first to the last and it looked good, the only issue is the fact that obviously images have sizing issues when it comes to making the site responsive, and the images take up unnecessary space on the server and effect loading times, depending on how many are used. My question is simple to ask if anyone knows of a more efficient way of creating a similar effect that can use plain text instead of images? Possibly by hiding all text bar one line within an element and then fading to the next line? Preferably using only CSS but js answers are welcome too. Thanks in advance!

Also, a website using images for the effect I want to achieve: http://portsmouthtap.co.uk/

Comment: well can you post whatever you've tried so far for us to start with?

Comment: The example site is using images but divs would work exactly the same. Looks like they have keyframed animations going on with individual animation delays.